# Regex for stripping a prefix

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got an existing Rewrite rule that adds a prefix of /us for US users and redirects them to different pages that contain the /us prefix (so 'page-1' is redirected to 'us/page-1'):

RewriteRule ^/(page-1|page-2|page-3|page-4)$ /us/$1 [redirect=temp,last]

I'm just needing the opposite of this rule for the home country of the site, so it strips the /us prefix for these 4 pages if someone from the home country navigates to these pages (so 'us/page-1' should become 'page-1').

I'm not needing the conditions, just the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only capture the part you care about.

```
RewriteRule ^/us/(page-\d)$ /$1
```